# add simulink block programmatically from within function

Tags: scope, simulink, workspace

Is there a way to add a simulink block programmatically from within a function? The principle works by using `add_block(...)` via script in the basic matlab workspace. But if i try to add a block from within a function, Matlab seems to dont see the simulink model anymore. I get the error `Invalid destination block specification`.

Any clue what to do? Thanks.

EDIT:  This `add_block('built-in/Gain','Model/blk')` worksin the command window, but it doesnt work inside a function.

Comment: Post some code, please

Comment: Yes that is absolutely possible. The target model has to be in memory already (`load_system('xxx')`). If you show some code we can help.

Comment: For example I use: `add_block('built-in/Gain','Model/blk')` in the command-window. This works. But Iit does not work inside a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it finally working, just had to change the current workspace. `evalin('Base',...)` does the trick.